# Is asking a question about the politeness of a phrase on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic

I'm looking at the FAQs and I'm trying to see if this has already been answered...Can't find it anywhere.

Is asking if a phrase is polite on topic? Wouldn't subjects like this be too subjective to personal opinion on what's polite and what's not polite?

Answer (score 2):

Well, we do have these (and many more, just search the site for "polite" or "rude"):

- [Is “Can I have a cup of coffee?” polite?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/is-can-i-have-a-cup-of-coffee-polite)
- [“Excuse Me”… Is it polite or just a terse way to ask others to step aside?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14982/excuse-me-is-it-polite-or-just-a-terse-way-to-ask-others-to-step-aside)
- [Is “thanks” appropriate to be polite in this situation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4343/is-thanks-appropriate-to-be-polite-in-this-situation)
- [Is “can” or “could” more polite?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7414/is-can-or-could-more-polite)
- [Is it considered rude language to omit interrogatives in speech?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27365/is-it-considered-rude-language-to-omit-interrogatives-in-speech)
- [How rude is “to eat like a pig”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30236/how-rude-is-to-eat-like-a-pig#30238)
- [How rude is “naff”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26034/how-rude-is-naff)
- [Is it rude to call a gay person “homosexual?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27057/is-it-rude-to-call-a-gay-person-homosexual)
- [Why is 'c*nt' so much more derogatory in the US than the UK?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7059/why-is-cnt-so-much-more-derogatory-in-the-us-than-the-uk)
- [What is currently the most obscene word in British English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11981/what-is-currently-the-most-obscene-word-in-british-english)

All of them open. Which, of course, is no guarantee that all future questions of this kind will stay open (and in fact, there's no guarantee that all of these old questions will), but I would say, go ahead and ask. I do recommend, however, that you have a look at the six guidelines for good subjective questions outlined in this [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), and word your question accordingly:

> Great subjective questions...
>
> 1. ... inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”.
> 2. ... tend to have long, not short, answers.
> 3. ... have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone.
> 4. ... invite sharing experiences over opinions.
> 5. ... insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references.
> 6. ... are more than just mindless social fun.

Comment: my only quarral with asking if a question is polite or rude is because English is the primary language in more than 6 countries and spoken in over 50 countries. All these countries have different social standards, so wouldn't it be impossible to give a solid answer to any 'manners' questions?

Comment: @OghmaOsiris: This is true of most aspects of language; that is, any quality answer, whether it deals with politeness, pronunciation, or syntax, should try to address the contexts and (English-speaking) cultures where the answer may vary.

Comment: Then i dont see how something that subjective can still be on topic.